# PHP Cookies: splash page works, then I get a redirect loop

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to build a web app in PHP's Laravel (5) framework, and the beginning of it would be a JS script that types some stuff on the screen and then shows a continue button, and the idea is that once the continue button is clicked (or once the user has seen that welcome page), they will no longer see it and will be redirected to the index page from there on out until the expiration, set to 10 years in the future.

When I first load the site, the welcome page appears. After loading the index page by just putting `/` as the url extension (since I haven't put a continue button yet), I get a redirect loop.

**Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

The `/welcome` is the url for the splash page, and the `/` is the url for the main index page.

The code below is located in the `/` directory, or `index.blade.php`

```
<?PHP
    $cookie = 'yum';
    $value = 'redirect'; 
    $expiration = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $domain = '/';

    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) {
        setcookie($cookie, $value, $expiration, $domain);
        header("Location: /welcome");
    } else {
        header("Location: /");
    }
?>
```

The code below is `routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.index');
});

Route::get('/welcome', function() {
    return view('pages.welcome');
});
```

The code below is `PagesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function welcome() {
        return view('pages.welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question both `/welcome` and `/` redirect to the same page, correct?

Comment: I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Lets get the obvious out of the way first. Are you sure it sets the cookie?

Comment: Yes, the cookie DOES get set. I changed it's name to `yum` from `welcome`, and the `/welcome` page loaded again, and then I tried to go to the `/` directory and got the redirect loop again. So yes, I believe the cookie is being set for sure.

Comment: I don't necessarily see anything wrong with your current code tbh. This seems to be more of a routing issue(well...obliviously). Can you include your `routes.php` file as well. I can only guestimate what the problem is so far. Btw, are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: Routes.php added. Laravel 5. Will clarify in question.

Comment: The only issue I see here is that the cookie is not set or not recognized properly. It's the only possible loop. Can you drop `!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])` and simply replace it with `if(false)` and see what happens?

Comment: Changed to `if(false)` and still getting the redirect loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85116/discussion-between-andrew-and-boy-wonder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the else statement, It's redirecting to itself.

It will solve the loop problem.